# Where to start with a HIPAA-compliant iOS app on AWS?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, hipaa

I'm researching pathways to developing a HIPAA-compliant iOS app in the healthcare space on AWS; I've found scattered information so am seeking additional guidance here on how to best prepare and where to start?

Answer (score 3):

The [HIPAA compliance page](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/hipaa-compliance/) is a great place to start, with links to whitepapers and other relevant information. If you are using React Native, [this tutorial by @dabit3](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-authentication-in-depth-8d8c2e4ad81b) helps with authentication basics. Feel free to comment if you'd like something more specific.

Comment: Okay; thanks for the info. More specifically: is there a way to combine this HIPAA Quick Start (https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/accelerator-hipaa/) with AWS Mobile Hub?

Comment: Sure, you can use mobile hub to bootstrap your development environment and use that referrence achitecture for runtime

Comment: Okay; do you have any more information on steps to implementing the bootstrapped development environment and code in the reference architecture for runtime?

Comment: Additionally, is there a service to upload existing code (from the development environment bootstrapped via mobile hub) in the Quick Start (HIPAA-compliant) architecture?

Comment: You can generate the app and download the source using Mobile Hub and start from there, and then add cloudformation template from the quickstart. But no way to "retrofit" existing code into the quick start, that should be just a reference and certainly needs some integration work to your software process.

Comment: Okay; so essentially, once we add the cloudformation template from the HIPAA quickstart, we can modify the endpoints in the awsconfiguration.json file generated from mobile hub to our new (& relevant) HIPAA-compliant services, and modify the rest of our environment to best support our software process?

Comment: Pretty much this, but needs changing the template to reference your app and that may not be so simple if you don't know cloudformation. A better idea may be starting with the plain mobilehub app and add the HIPAA reference resources gradually as needed.

Comment: so is there any other resource for this question that we find for mobile app?